# XCode 4. How to remove target action method properly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

In my storyboard I have a UIButton. I create target action handler by pressing the ctrl keyboard button and drugging the button to a ViewController.m . Then after while I removed the target action method and reset this btn other method. But when I touch on that button,  the runtime error appears.

`It says: -[CalculatorViewController piPressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a65b30`

Where piPressed is the old removed method.

**Hi to remove an old target action method correctly?**

Comment: How are you adding and removing the targets?

Comment: @ott,  On the left side of the XCode window  I had the storyboard with the button in there. On the right side is CalculatorViewController.m file.  1)'How did I add the target'. I select the button, pressed the keyboard ctrl key, then dragged the button to the CalculatorViewController.m . The target action method is appeared. 2) How did I remove the target. I just select the code of the target action method and remove it by press keyboard backspace button.

Comment: I haven't done this via storyboard, only by methods [button addTarget:... and removeTarget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the button press **⌥ ⌘ 2** and remove the unwanted method from the inspector window.

or

Just **right click on the button** (on story board) remove the unwanted methods appeared from the appeared window.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to remove method. In the storyboad it is necessarily to select the button -> right click -> sent events -> remove unnecessary method.